# Reduce com sort

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso reduzir um `array`, somando os valore (consegui fazendo o código abaixo), agora com essa redução preciso fazer uma espécie de um `SORT` para depois pegar os 3 maiores e os outros vou fazer tipo um if para outros
Não sei se tem um `lib` em `nodejs` que facilitaria.

1. REDUCE
2. ORDENAR PELO TRES MAIORES

   ```
      var array=[ {

           "paymentId" : 1,
           "value" : 290
       },
       {
           "paymentId" : 2,
           "value" : 223
       },
       {
           "paymentId" : 1,
           "value" : 2333
       },
       {
           "paymentId" : 3,
           "value" : 24432
       },
       {
           "paymentId" : 4,
           "value" : 23424
       },
       {
           "paymentId" : 5,
           "value" : 2323
       },
   ]
   var r = array.reduce(function(pv, cv) {
       if ( pv[cv.paymentId] ) {
           pv[cv.paymentId] += cv.value;
       } else {
           pv[cv.paymentId] = cv.value;
       }
       return pv;
   }, {});

   console.log(r);
   ```

**EXEMPLO DE RESULTADO  O 0 SERIA PARA OUTROS**

```
[
    {
        "paymentId" : 3,
        "value" : 24423
    },
    {
        "paymentId" : 4,
        "value" : 23424
    },
    {
        "paymentId" : 1,
        "value" : 2623
    },
    {
        "paymentId" : 0,
        "value" : 2222
    },   
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você vai transformar o array num objeto para poder acessar os ids pelo índice, recomendo armazenar o objeto interno inteiro nesses índices, não apenas seu valor, já que o resultado final deve manter o mesmo formato.

```
var obj = array.reduce((pv, cv) => {
    if (pv[cv.paymentId]) pv[cv.paymentId].value += cv.value
    else pv[cv.paymentId] = {...cv}
    return pv
}, {})
```

Agora para poder organiza-lo por meio do método `sort`, você precisa converte-lo de volta para um array, pois não tem como organizar uma estrutura onde os valores estão associados a uma chave.

```
var arrayOrdenado = Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
```

E a soma dos demais resultados pode ser obtida com reduce:

```
var resto = {
    paymentId: 0,
    value: resultado.slice(3).reduce((acc, r) => acc + r.value, 0)
}
```

Funcionamento:

```js
var array = [{"paymentId":1,"value":290},{"paymentId":2,"value":223},{"paymentId":1,"value":2333},{"paymentId":3,"value":24432},{"paymentId":4,"value":23424},{"paymentId":5,"value":2323}]

var obj = array.reduce((pv, cv) => {
    if (pv[cv.paymentId]) pv[cv.paymentId].value += cv.value
    else pv[cv.paymentId] = {...cv}
    return pv
}, {})

var arrayOrdenado = Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)

var resultado = arrayOrdenado.slice(0, 3).concat({
    paymentId: 0,
    value: arrayOrdenado.slice(3).reduce((acc, r) => acc + r.value, 0)
})

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: Genial, muito obrigado pela resposta amigo

Comment: Qual melhor forma que você usaria para encontrar os 3 primeiros e o resto colocar no mesmo valor como outros ?
Exemplo 
`
[ { paymentId: 3, value: 24432 },
  { paymentId: 4, value: 23424 },
  { paymentId: 1, value: 2623 },
  { paymentId: 0, value: 2546 },
`

Onde o 0 seria a soma dos restante(outros)